# How do I initialize a struct containing another struct?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm new and i try to create a struct of stuct on C code. I don't understand how i can inizialize a struct of struct. Someneone help me?
I have:

```
#define SIZEHOSP 200
#define DIM 200
#define SIZESICK 2000



typedef struct SICKREGION {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char fiscalCode[16];
    enum stateSick;
    diagnosisDate data;
    healingDate dataH;
};

typedef struct HOSPITAL {
    char nameHospital[30];
    int codeHospital;
    char addressHospital[40];
    char departmentManager[30];
    int beds;
    int bedsIntensiveCare;
};

HOSPITAL hospital[SIZEHOSP];

typedef struct REGION {
    char nameRegion[20];
    int codeRegion;
    char MainTownRegion[15];
    char namePresidentRegion[20];
    int numberHospital;
    int numberSickRegion;
    HOSPITAL hospital[SIZEHOSP];
    SICKREGION sickregion[SIZESICK];
};

REGION region[DIM] = {
    {"Sicilia", 0004, "Palermo", "Musumeci", 40, 150},
    {"sardegna", 4444, "cagliari", "pippo", 200, 50},
    {"calabria", 0000, "reggio", "Josh", 12, 18}
};
```

for example i inizialized 3 type of REGION. but they are incomplete because i don't know how insert the value of structure HOSPITAL and SICKREGION inside the region[DIM]. What is the syntax? I hope he explained the problem well.

Comment: Use nested `{}` to initialize structure elements, e.g. `{1, 2, {3, 4}, 5}`.

Comment: this code will not compile despite of initialisation. Post the actual code.

Comment: @Alberto Torrisi This  typedef struct diagnosisDate, healingDate{
unsigned int day;
char month[20];
unsigned int year;}; is incorrect and does not make sense.

Comment: ok, thank you. And how i print the variable region[0]?

Comment: ok guys i did it :D a lot of hours for print the structure...
Thank you for the fastttt reply of everyone! I hope to be a pro dev in the future for help the community :)

Comment: Initializing the `REGION` structures this way might be tedious because they contain arrays of structures. In your example for "Sicilia" you would have to add 40 `HOSPITAL` structures and 150 `SICKREGION` structures (if I understand your intention right).Note that the C compiler will interpret numbers starting with 0 as octal numbers. It doesn't matter for  youre region code `0004`, but it would make a difference for e.g. `0123` which is 1*64+2*8+3=83.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How do I initialize a struct containing another struct?*

There are several ways to initialize a struct.  To simplify, the following example uses smaller structs than those you provided...

The following will illustrate initialization with initialization with values ( `= {,,,{,,}};` ), then with zeros `= {0}` :

```
typedef struct {
    int count;
    float cash;
    char item[50];
}Purchase;

typedef struct {
    int accnt;
    char acct_name[50];
    Purchase purch;
} Acct;

Acct acct = {100123, "Robert Baily", {15, 12.50, "Tires"}};
//Or, using member names to self document the initialization statement as suggested in comments:
Acct acct1 = Acct acct = {.accnt=100123, .acct_name="Robert Baily", {.count=15, .cash=12.50, .item="Tires"}};

Acct acct2 = {0};

int main(void)
{
    printf("acct = %d\nAcct_name = %s\nitem = %s\ncount = %d\ncash = %3.2f\n", acct.accnt, acct.acct_name, acct.purch.item, acct.purch.count, acct.purch.cash);
    printf("acct2 = %d\nAcct_name = %s\nitem = %s\ncount = %d\ncash = %3.2f\n", acct2.accnt, acct2.acct_name, acct2.purch.item, acct2.purch.count, acct2.purch.cash);
    return 0;
}
```

Although these are small, they illustrate what you are doing with your larger, more complicated structs.  I suggest that for your structs it will be extremely tedious, and probably not necessary to use the first method.   `struct` declaration in an actual program is often initialized by zeroing.  i.e. `{0}`

Comment: I prefer `= {.accnt = 100123 ...` to avoid silly errors\

Comment: @P__J__ - provide an example what this would look like for a `char []` variable which is a member of the struct member.  eg `acct.purch.item = "Tires"` does not work.

Comment: @P__J__ - If my edit address your question, can we please clean up the comments?  Thanks.